# Como fazer uma requisição ajax que retorne um texto em html?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, ruby-on-rails, async

Supondo que o link que faça a requisição seja:

```
<%= link_to 'New Classroom', new_classroom_path,class: :remote_link, remote: true %>
```

E que o tratamento do retorno da mesma seja:

```
$('.remote_link').bind('ajax:success',function(e, data, status, xhr) {
    ajax_replace(data.responseText, status, xhr)
  });

function ajax_replace(data, textStatus, request)
{
    replace_html(data,request.getResponseHeader("content_id"));
}
```

No qual é o texto html retornado substitui o texto html encontrado na div que tenha a mesma id que a armazenada no header "content_id"

O método que trada a requisição no servidor é:

```
after_filter :set_featured_id

def new
    @classroom = Classroom.new
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js{render :new, formats: [:html]; head :ok}
    end  
end 

def set_featured_id
    response.headers['content_id'] = 'featured'
end
```

No qual um método inclui o valor requerido no cabeçalho após a execução do tratamento.

O problema é que apesar do valor setado no cabeçalho ser recuperado corretamente, o valor renderizado não é encontrado como responseText.

Comment: Não seria algo como data.body e não data.responseText?

Comment: @user5020, acredito que `responseText` seja uma propriedade de `jqXHR xhr` e não de `PlainObject data `. então tente utilizar `xhr.responseText`, em tdo caso, tente fazer um exemplo completo, inclusive com a requisição `AJAX`, você pode simular uma usando uma URL em memoria, como no seguinte [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/whrtnp25/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

não precisa utilizar o formato js, utilize o html e deixe o layout como falso

```
#exemplo
format.html{ render '/products/new', layout: false } if request.xhr?
```

ai quando receber a resposta do servidor ele vai mandar exatamente o conteudo que está em new.html.erb menos o layout da pagina, se eu entendi é isso que você quer certo?